# The state variable returned after using useState react hook shows .map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, map-function

This code gives me error when I try to map the state variable returned after calling useEffect hook.
On console, when I print the myAppointment it shows two values one is empty ([]) and other (Array[25]) I want to extract the petname values from this array . But getting error "map is not a function" Please look into it and help me!

```
function App() {
  const [myAppointment, setmyAppointment] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
      fetch('./data.json')
      .then(response=> response.json())
      .then(result=>{
        const apts=result.map(item=>{
          return item
        })
        setmyAppointment(state=>({...state,
          myAppointment:apts
        }))
      })**strong text**
  },[])

  console.log(myAppointment)
  const listItem = myAppointment.map((item)=>{
    return(
      <div>{item.petName}</div>
    )
  })

  return (
    <main className="page bg-white" id="petratings">
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12 bg-white">
          <div className="container">
            {/* {listItem} */}
            <div><AddAppointment /></div>
            <div><SearchAppointment /></div>
            <div><ListAppointment /></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your `setmyAppointment()` call turns `myAppointment` into an object, arrays use square brackets: `[...]`. You probably want `.then(result => setmyAppointment([...myAppointment, result]));` (`useState()` creates separate state variables; you don't use it like `this.setState()` where you have to pass the key: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: setmyAppointment(state=>([...state,
          myAppointment:apts
        ]))   You mean like this I should write?

Comment: You can actually use `setmyAppointment(result)`, since you don't have to append to an existing array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have you state as an array. However when you try to update it you convert it into an object with key `myAppointment` which is the cause of your error.

You must update your state like

```
  setmyAppointment(state=> [...state, ...apts]);
```

However since the state is initially empty and you only update it once in useEffect on initialLoad, you could also update it like

```
 setmyAppointment(apts);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is from the way you're setting your state after the data is fetched.

You're setting the state as an object by instead of an array.

Let's Take a look at the line where you set the state.

```js
setmyAppointment(state=>({...state,
          myAppointment:apts
        }))
```

Using the spread operator with curly braces tells JavaScript compiler to spread an object, and obviously that's not what you want.

What you ought to do is instead of curly braces, use square brackets. That will tell the compiler you want to spread an array.

So it should be something like this .

```js
setmyAppointment(state=>([...state
        ]))
```

And if I were you, I will do this a little bit different.
I will set the state like this

```js
setmyAppointment(apt)
```

I hope this helps